# Where is the Authoritative Name Server Information storing?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

Short Version:

Where does `host -t ns github.com` getting the answers?

Long Version:

In slide 7 of [this google slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1HfXVJyXElzBshZ9SYNjBwJf_4MBaho6UcATTFwApfXw/preview?sle=true#slide=id.g349e2a1f1_0111), for the last two stops: If "x.root-servers.net" do not know the domain, It will ask the "Authoritative Name Server" for it. The problem is Who tell the "Authoritative Name Server" (info, aka IP) back to root servers?

I did read [an article related](http://www.dnsknowledge.com/whatis/authoritative-name-server/), but I still do not know the answer.

I know the `whois` lookup will fetch information (including the name servers) for the domain name, is this the way routers get the "Authoritative Name Server" info?

Which server is storing the information of the Authoritative Name Server? A server from the domain name registrar?

**Edited**:

I don't understand why you (expert) guys vote this as off-topic. I've read (and read it just again) the FAQ of Serverfault and don't think this is off topic. It did say you can ask questions about "Network routing, switches, and firewalls".

I'm not requesting all the education things about the whole dns-loopup routes but only not understand one step - Where the Authoritative server info is saved. If this is not place to ask this, where should I? SO.com?

**Edit 2**:

- Updated the title
- Have got the answer from oo: the gTLD Servers hold the data.

Comment: The root servers store the name servers of the TLD zones. The TLD zones store the name servers of the second level zones. And so on. It's a hierarchy.

Comment: I think that it's worth explicitly noting that whois is an entirely separate protocol from dns and plays no part at all in dns lookups. Whois only serves as a means of providing domain name registration metadata (in the context of domain names, it's also used in some other contexts). The data provided by whois is primarily for human consumption as the data is a free-form blob of text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Hopefully, this will be a little clearer for you, even though it's a bit wordy.*

That part of the slide is slightly incorrect -- the root servers don't ask any other servers for records on your behalf. In that example, all of the heavy lifting is done by Google's 8.8.8.8 server

To better explain this, you first need to know the difference between an authoritative DNS server, and a recursive DNS server.

#### Authoritative vs. Recursive DNS

An authoritative DNS server will only respond with answers for records which it hosts. If you try to ask an authoritative server for a record which it's not responsible for, it will tell you either "No." (REFUSED) or tell you where to look (NOERROR, and a list of servers in the AUTHORITY section of the DNS packet).

A recursive DNS server (e.g. your Linksys, your ISP, Google's 8.8.8.8, etc), will try to the best of its ability to follow the chain of DNS server referrals until it can get to an authoritative server to get an answer. This is also known as "DNS recursion".

#### Root Servers and Referrals

The root servers (x.root-servers.net) act as authoritative DNS servers at the top of the DNS tree (.), which tell the requester what is the next DNS server they should look for.

Typically, the root servers will refer you to a gTLD server for the TLD in question (.com, .net, .org, etc).

#### Domain Registrars and gTLD Servers

When you register a domain, you're required to enter a set of DNS servers (or use your registrar's own).

At the time of domain registration (or an update), your domain registrar sends an update to the respective generic top-level domain servers (or gTLD servers), which are responsible for handing out referrals for the TLD in question (.com, .net, .org, .uk, etc).

The update basically says "Hey, in the future, whenever someone asks about github.com, refer them to ns1.p16.dynect.net, ns2.p16.dynect.net, ns3.p16.dynect.net, and ns4.p16.dynect.net".

The gTLD server holds onto this information until it's changed by the registrar.

#### The Query: From Root, to gTLD, to Github

When you ask a.root-servers.net for "www.github.com" ("dig www.github.com @a.root-servers.net"), its response is:

"I don't know about github.com specifically, but I can tell you that any of these DNS servers for .com can give you a better answer".

```
$ dig www.github.com @a.root-servers.net

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.github.com @a.root-servers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52400
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 14
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.github.com.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
m.gtld-servers.net. 172800  IN  A   192.55.83.30
l.gtld-servers.net. 172800  IN  A   192.41.162.30
k.gtld-servers.net. 172800  IN  A   192.52.178.30
j.gtld-servers.net. 172800  IN  A   192.48.79.30
i.gtld-servers.net. 172800  IN  A   192.43.172.30
h.gtld-servers.net. 172800  IN  A   192.54.112.30
g.gtld-servers.net. 172800  IN  A   192.42.93.30
f.gtld-servers.net. 172800  IN  A   192.35.51.30
e.gtld-servers.net. 172800  IN  A   192.12.94.30
d.gtld-servers.net. 172800  IN  A   192.31.80.30
c.gtld-servers.net. 172800  IN  A   192.26.92.30
b.gtld-servers.net. 172800  IN  A   192.33.14.30
b.gtld-servers.net. 172800  IN  AAAA    2001:503:231d::2:30
a.gtld-servers.net. 172800  IN  A   192.5.6.30

;; Query time: 17 msec
;; SERVER: 198.41.0.4#53(198.41.0.4)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 28 05:38:56 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 492
```

So, now you have a list of servers that can tell you about .com domains. Next when you ask one of the gTLD servers you were referred to ("dig www.github.com @a.gtld-servers.net"), its response is:

"I don't know about www.github.com specifically, but I can tell you that any of these servers for github.com can give you a better answer".

```
$ dig www.github.com @a.gtld-servers.net

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.github.com @a.gtld-servers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9895
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.github.com.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
github.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns3.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns4.p16.dynect.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.p16.dynect.net. 172800  IN  A   208.78.70.16
ns3.p16.dynect.net. 172800  IN  A   208.78.71.16
ns2.p16.dynect.net. 172800  IN  A   204.13.250.16
ns4.p16.dynect.net. 172800  IN  A   204.13.251.16

;; Query time: 43 msec
;; SERVER: 192.5.6.30#53(192.5.6.30)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 28 05:40:14 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 182
```

And finally, when you ask one of the designated servers you were referred to ("dig www.github.com @ns1.p20.dynect.net"), its response is:

"Ah yes! I know this one, www.github.com is a nickname for github.com, and github.com has an IP address of 192.30.252.129".

```
dig www.github.com @ns1.p16.dynect.net

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.github.com @ns1.p16.dynect.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35620
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.github.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.github.com.     3600    IN  CNAME   github.com.
github.com.     30  IN  A   192.30.252.128

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
github.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns3.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns1.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns4.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns2.p16.dynect.net.

;; Query time: 25 msec
;; SERVER: 208.78.70.16#53(208.78.70.16)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 28 05:57:19 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 148
```

Recursive DNS servers are responsible for traversing this chain of referrals until they get an answer to give back to you. This is typically what your ISP's DNS servers do on your behalf.

Your browser (or whatever application you're using), waits until your recursive DNS server does all the heavy lifting and returns a single answer to you. All of this tends to happen in a brief amount of time, measured in milliseconds -- even faster if the recursive DNS server already has the answer in its cache.

Comment: `dig +trace +add example.com` maybe helpful as a single command that shows the chain of delegations.

Comment: Thank you oo, I'm very appreciate for your detailed answer, though I'm not asking the whole steps (I already knew them). So the answer is "The x.gtld-servers.net." is storing the Authoritative Namer Server Info", right? So for a domain like "good.im", the servers "hoppy.iom.com., etc" (got by `dig +trace good.im`) hold the Authoritative Namer Server Information for ever until the Registrar server (the user) send a change request, right?

Comment: @mitnk Yes, that is correct.